# Angular Service Subtractive Filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an Angular service and I'm trying to return a filtered data set, using Javascript's `Array.prototype.filter()` method. I'm matching multiple input objects' `key` `value` pairs to another set of object's `key` `value` pairs and returning the object if they match.

Here is my service:

```
app.service('scatterService', function(inputService) {
    return function(data) {
        var inputs = inputService.selectedInModel(); // returns 1 - 4 user input objects
        function getSelected(inputs) {
            return data.filter(function(obj) {
                // for each user input that exists
                angular.forEach(inputs, function(val, id) {
                    var dataProp = val['inData'];
                    // if prop value in data = prop value in user input
                    if (obj[dataProp] == val['value']) {
                        // returns objects that have *either* of the user inputs
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                });
            });
        }
        var newData = getSelected(inputs);
        console.log(newData);
    };
});
```

This returns a set of objects which contain properties with either `value` "a" or `value` "b", but one of the two. I want this to return only objects that have *both a and b values*. So if there are four theoretical user inputs, each input selected by the user shrinks the data more and more. Or, only return the items that have all of the input values.

I also want this to be able to functionally filter up to 4 potential inputs.

**Edit: Adding Object Structure**

```
inputs: {
    'entertainment': {
        id: 'entertainment',
        inData: 'Ent',
        value: '',
    },
    'TV': {
        id: 'TV',
        inData: 'tv',
        value: '17'
    },
    'Radio': {
        id: 'radio',
        inData: 'radio',
        value: 'JackFM'  
    }
},
```

**data**: 300+ items

```
data = [
    {
        id: '12345',
        Ent: 30,
        tv: 33
    },
    {
        id: 'TV',
        tv: 17,
        Ent: 999
    }
    // ... and so on
]
```

Comment: I think it might help to see a sample of what `data` and `inputs` could look like

Comment: Sure, I'll make that edit.

Comment: Added input and matching objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Focusing on your `Array.prototype.filter` section:

```
return data.filter(function(obj) {
    // for each user input that exists
    angular.forEach(inputs, function(val, id) {
        var dataProp = val['inData'];
        // if prop value in data = prop value in user input
        if (obj[dataProp] == val['value']) {
            // returns objects that have *either* of the user inputs
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

You are immediately returning `true` when you find a matching property value - which causes the `obj` to be selected by the filter when *any one* of the values match.

Instead, you could build up the result using the boolean *AND* operator over each of the inputs. The result will be `true` if and only if each of the intermediate input tests were `true`. If any one failed, the result will be `false`.

```
return data.filter(function(obj) {
    // result tracks if this is a matching obj
    // initially assume that it is
    var result = true;

    // for each user input that exists
    angular.forEach(inputs, function(val, id) {
        var dataProp = val['inData'];
        // AND the current result value with this input's test 
        result = result && obj[dataProp] === val['value'];
    });

    // return the resulting chain of ANDs
    return result;
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't `result` only track whether or not the previous value matched, and not whether or not the ones before that one did?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand that question? `result` is reset each time we look at a new `obj` - for each item in `data` - and `result` is always only looking at a single `obj` at a time.

Comment: Sorry, it took me a little bit to understand what you were doing here with the `&&` chaining. This is a great answer and solves my problem. Well thought out and explained, too.